# SQL Server SSIS Support for Access

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Does the scheduler in SQL Server for SSIS has support to run Access Queries and Reports?
I have a package that is scheduled on the Server but I need to add a Script Task that will execute a macro inside an Access file. Does the server has support to execute a macro inside an Access file?

Comment: Yes but it will be unreliable as MS Access is an interactive application. It is not recommended to run interactive applications inside any unattended scheduling tool.

Comment: I googled and found  any examples of how you can do it, generally through VBScript, but they will all be unreliable